Threejs clipping a wall
I have a 3d channel that contains cylinders which simulate a liquid.
here's an example
The issue is that the cylinders can overlap with the walls and show through them.
I think i need to use clipping planes to solve this. Computing the planes is not an issue, but as I understand it, I would need to know the inner normals of the channel walls to determine which direction of the plane should get  rendered? I do not have those. How can I solve this? Or is there another way to do it?

You DO have the normals, you just need to do math to get them, and three.js can help.
Consider your "channel" has a plane that is constructed parallel to the YZ plane, and faces -X. In that case, the normal is easy: let nor = new Vector3( -1, 0, 0 )
But what about the case where you have an curved corner? As long as you know how the arc of the curve is defined, you can also find the normals in whatever increments around the curve you want.
For the inside wall:

Take a normal in a starting direction facing away from the center of the arc, like let nor = new Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ) would be a unit vector in the +X direction
If your arc wraps around the Y axis, then use create a second vector to capture that information: let axis = new Vector3( 0, 1, 0 )
Use Vector3.applyAxisAngle to rotate your normal vector some increment of your choosing (in radians). nor.applyAxisAngle( axis, rad )

That's it. That's the normal for your inner wall. For your outer wall, do the same, but use Vector3.negate to invert the normal:

nor.negate()

Now, for each position, you'll need to define a clipping plane. That's fine because Material.clippingPLanes is an Array. But beyond that, you may need to take steps to ensure the planes don't interfere with each other (planes are infinite in every planar direction). Take a look at the Clipping Intersection example for ways you can avoid clipping plane cross-talk.
